# Remove spaces from certain JtextField in java netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextfield

I want to remove spaces from a JtextField, so when the user click the button it automatically removes the space from the text he/she wrote.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Use a DocumentFilter, then you can prevent the user from entering a space in the text field so there is no need to do the edit when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply, you need to add an action listener to the button which the user is going to click.
for example: the button will be for posting something. "POST"

```
public class YourProject extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JtextField text = new JtextField();
JButton post = new JButton("POST");

public YourProject(){

add(text);
add(post);
post.addactionlistener(this);
setVisible(true);

}



 @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

if(e.getSource()==post) {

String removed = text.getText().trim();

System.out.println(removed);

}
```

If the user writes "Hello World" then clicks post, the output will be "HelloWorld".
hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This would replace every space with empty string:

```
String text = txtField.getText().replaceAll("\\s+", "");

// or just
// String text = txtField.getText().replace(" ", "");
```

If you just need to remove trailing and leading spaces, then do this:

```
String text = txtField.getText().trim();
```

---

and finally set your new text into the text field:

```
textField.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String sessi = textField.getText();
System.out.println(sessi.replaceAll(" ",""));
```

would work for you.