# How to create a case insensitive JTextField, which would ignore white spaces?

Tags: java, string, oop, whitespace

Here's my problem.
I have a JTextField in which a user inputs a String. 
In the action controller I am checking if the written String corresponds to another String contained in an object.
I would like to make the JTextField case insensitive to whitespaces. 
I will really appreciate your help.

[Edited]
Solved it more easily, using replaceAll("\s+", "") on the Strings; 
Thank you all for promptness.
Kinds regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879695/remove-spaces-from-certain-jtextfield-in-java-netbeans ... can that help you? (second answer)

Comment: "case insensitive to whitespaces" is quite a bit unclear. Do you want the JTextField to convert all letters to upper or lower case? Do you want it to not display any whitespace? If so, look into using either a DocumentFilter or a JFormattedTextField. If you only care about how the program processes the text on event, then the question has nothing to do with JTextField and all to do with how you write your event listener. Please clarify.

Comment: can you not take the text as written, and then define a comparator that ignores case and whitespace?  that way you don't need to subclass a GUI component for something that is essentially a business rule question

Comment: I'm sorry, but case sensitivity and white space are two totally different things. Next time try to be more clear about your requirements so we don't have to guess

Comment: It seems the question is not clear enough.

Comment: @ultrajohn: it's clear enough to be eventually answerable, but did require that a bunch of non-explained information be extracted from the original poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
st.replaceAll("\\s+","")
```

removes all whitespaces and non visible characters such as tab and newline. You can use this on the string you get from your `JTextField`. This is a [Regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

**Edit**: the `string.trim()` method is not what you want, because it trims the whitespaces from the start and end of the string, rather than getting rid of all of the whitespace.

**Edit 2:** If you want to compare strings, use `string.equals(str2)`

For example, if you have a license plate string called `st = "AAA 111"` and another called `st2 = "AAA111'` just strip them of whitespace like this `st.replaceAll("\\s+","")` and `st2.replaceAll("\\s+","")` and then you can check if they are equals by `st.equals(st2)`.

Comment: @mrainman: again, this makes no sense. JTextFields don't "compare" anything. You're ignoring the real issue -- your event listener -- while concentrating on the wrong issue -- the JTextField.

Comment: @mrainman: for example, where exactly are you comparing the text? In a JButton's ActionListener?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can you use the FormattedTextField [(docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#maskformatter)

```
JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(this.createFormatter("UUU-###")); // 3 any character uppercase and 3 any valid number

public MaskFormatter createFormatter(String s) {
    MaskFormatter formatter = null;
    try {
        formatter = new MaskFormatter(s);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException exc) {
        System.err.println("formatter is bad: " + exc.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
 return formatter;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want your JTextField to ignore white-spaces that are being typed by the user in real-time, you can try the code below. This solution overrides the action of keyTyped event of your JTextField.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class CustomListenerTextField {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame Canvas");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);


        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (Character.isWhitespace(e.getKeyChar()) || Character.isSpaceChar(e.getKeyChar())){
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

            }
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        frame.add(field);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void GuessButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
//This is the action event of the button.
                                       
    if (GuessTextField.getText().replaceAll("\\s+","").equalsIgnoreCase("what"))
//Ignores the case of the specified TextField.
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You're Awesome");
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Guess Again");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are discouraged, as they provide no insight on how the code solves the problem. Please update your solution to explain how your code solves the OP's problem :)